# How to Integrate Signalr 2 with Angular 1.4 and Web API 2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, signalr, signalr-hub

I include the reference in the begeining of HTML

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

I add  angular js file here:

<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Controller/TransacCltr.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Services/CrudService.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="TransacCtrl">
       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="SaveUpdate()">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my TransacCltr.js file I write this code:

```
app.controller('TransacCtrl', ['$scope', 'CrudService', 'Notification',
    function ($scope, CrudService, Notification) {

    $scope.transac = {};
    $scope.btnText = "Save";      
    //method
    $scope.SaveUpdate = SaveUpdate;
    $scope.GetServiceTypeList = GetServiceTypeList;
    $scope.StatusOk = StatusOk;  
    init();
    function init()
    {
        initilize();
    }
    function initilize()
    {
        Connect();          
    }
    var SignalrConnection;
    function Connect() {
        SignalrConnection = $.connection.myHub;         
        //connecting the client to the signalr hub
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("Connected to Signalr Server");
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("failed in connecting to the signalr server");
        })
    }
    function SaveUpdate() { 
        var Temperature = parseInt($scope.transac.TrancAmount);
        //calling the ChangeWeather function on the signalr server   
        SignalrConnection.server.change_weather(Temperature)

            }
        }

    }

}]);
```

$.connection.myHub; this is shown me undefined.Why it show this?
if it is undefined how it will be defined.If I use it normal jquery function it does not show this message.But If I use it in angularjs then shows the error message.How I can solve this error?Any help is greately apprecited.

My Hub Class this is given below:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{  
    static int Temperature;
    [HubMethodName("change_weather")]
    public void ChangeWeather(int temperature)
    {
        //change the temperature   
        Temperature = temperature;  
        Clients.Others.NotifyUser(temperature);
    }
    [HubMethodName("get_weather")]
    public void GetWeather()
    {
        //pushing the data only to the user which has called this method.   
        Clients.Caller.NotifyUser(Temperature);
    }  
}
```